# PSD (photoshop) editing on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, adobe-photoshop, psd

I have a PSD for a website that must be sliced. I can not work in Win or OSX box(or a virtual machine).

What are the solutions for editing a PSD in Ubuntu 9.10?
Which one do you recommend?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) (GNU Image Manipulation Program) can open PSD files.

Comment: Hmm.. I have tried GIMP, but apparently it doesn't display correctly some of the layers (i mean id doesn't display them at all :) ). I will try a GIMP fork project, called CinePaint.

Comment: As takeshin said, PSD is a closed format so GIMP probably will never completely offer full PSD support.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you may consider *buying* Windows XP, then *buying* and upgrade to Windows 7, next *buying* Photoshop CS3, then *buying* an upgrage to Adobe Creative suite CS4, and…

or…
You may just install [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) from the command line:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Then click the .psd and you will be happy :)

To see additional goodies for Gimp, try:

```
sudo apt-cache search gimp
```

(Note, that PSD format is a closed, Adobe Photoshop specific one. And if you want to use all the Photoshop features like smart objects, nested layer sets, *buying* is your only option. But for most of the basic use cases - Gimp is fine too).

Good news: I heard that some guys are using Photoshop with wine.

Answer (score 1):

GIMP won't open all .psd files but Libre office will open .psd files

Answer (score 1):

Krita is best for editing/opening .psd files in ubuntu. GIMP will not open the .psd files by default and may need further plugins, which might be complicated. Krita opens the .psd files without further plugins.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Krita, the ultimate weapon in the armoury of a Linux-based digital painter’s, now is at version 2.8. New tools make it more interesting for creating game art, and full Windows support is a bit of a game changer.

News Features in Krita 2.8:

```
Wrap Around mode to create seamless tiled textures from your current artwork ((use the W key, works in OpenGL mode only);
Clone Array tool to create isometric tiles.
New high-quality scaling mode for the OpenGL-based canvas.
Picking a layer by pressing R and clicking on a feature from that layer.
Configurable transparency visualization.
New dockable dialog to manage color swatches.
Easy expansion of canvas (deliberately not like in MyPaint, by users’ request).
Composition guides in the Crop tool.
```

Install Krita:

Ubuntu users can always get the latest version of Krita from the Krita Lime PPA. So far, it supports Ubuntu 13.10, Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 12.10. Ubuntu 14.04 will come with the 2.8 release by default.

To install Krita 2.8, press Ctrl+Alt+T on keyboard to open terminal. When it opens, run the commands below one by one:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dimula73/krita

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install krita-2.8

Answer (score 0):

Quite honestly the honest and true answer is there is no known solution and I wish there was.  Yes GIMP and a few other programs can open Photoshop .psd files but none can edit or interact the same way as Adobe Photoshop (not even the basics like editing text).  In Linux what I do is use a Windows virtual machine (VirtualBox) running Photoshop inside which basically runs at native speed.  I would love a Linux native or OpenSource solution but this doesn't look likely to happen unfortunately.